# Flutter - How to show a `snackbar` in `Future`

Tags: android, ios, dart, flutter, flutter-layout

In my flutter app, I am sending data from mobile to server. That part is done like below.

**register.dart**

```
void _createUser()
  {
    DataFetch().createUser(AppNavigation.getAPIUrl() +
          "user/saveUser", user).then((String result){
            print("RESULT IS: "+result);
          });
  }
```

**data_fetch.dart**

```
Future<String> createUser(String url, User body) async {
    print("BODY: " + body.toJson().toString());

    return http.post(url, body: convert.json.encode(body.toJson()), headers: {
      "Accept": "application/json",
      "content-type": "application/json"
    }).then((http.Response response) {
      final int statusCode = response.statusCode;

      print("RESPONSE: " + response.body);
      print("STATUS CODE: " + statusCode.toString());

      if (statusCode < 200 || statusCode > 400 || response.body == null) {
        throw new Exception("Error while fetching data");
      } else {
        return response.body;
      }
    });
  }
```

My UI is in **register.dart** and **data_fetch.dart** is a separate class with methods for supporting various data pass work.

I need to show a `snackbar` until the data save completes. I know I can use a `FutureBuilder` there is no use of attaching it as a widget where it returns some UI, because I have no UI to show after data is saved. I am trying to send data to server and I just need to indicate that.

How can I do this? There seems no such facility in `Future` anyway.

Answer (score 6):

create a key for your scaffold like this:

```
var _key = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
```

then attach it with your scaffold:

```
Scaffold(
    key: _key,
    body: your_ui_here,
)
```

pass this key to your future

```
void _createUser(var key)
  {
    DataFetch().createUser(AppNavigation.getAPIUrl() +
          "user/saveUser", user).then((String result){
            key.currentState.showSnackbar(
          Snackbar(content:Text("hello"))
      );
          });
  }
```

You can pass this key anywhere and it will work as long as the attached Scaffold is not disposed.

Answer (score 0):

With the current Flutter you have to use `ScaffoldMessenger`:

Global variable:

```
final GlobalKey<ScaffoldMessengerState> scaffoldMessengerKey = GlobalKey<ScaffoldMessengerState>();
```

To display a `SnackBar` message from `Future`:

```
scaffoldMessengerKey.currentState!.showSnackBar(SnackBar(...));
```

Create app as:

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return MaterialApp(
    home: ScaffoldMessenger(
      key: scaffoldMessengerKey,
        child: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
        ...
```